# Duplex Printing in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, ms-word, duplex

Can anyone help me out with duplex in vb.net for word document?

```
Dim odoc as word.document

odoc=Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument

odoc.printout()
```

How to duplex it?

Comment: I had the same problem and here's my solution easily adaptable to Word: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33239717/2559297

Answer (score 0):

That's a printer property, not a document or word property. See here: [PrinterSettings.Duplex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.duplex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks For Reply. can you please give me some guid on with it? as i have also tried to use the property called can duplex with print document but its dosn't work for me.. :(

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right printer to set the properties? What does CanDuplex return? Is your printer acutally able to print duplex? Do you get any error messages? Does it print at all?

Comment: yup Can Duplex returns TRUE. means my printer can duplex but when i print its print as normal not as duplex, from my understanding its because i print the word doc.. here is the example code               dim pd as new printdocument   dim odoc as word.document=globls.thisaddins.application.active document   if pd.printersetting can.duplex=true then   odoc.printout()  end if     thnx

Comment: You only ask the printer if it CAN duplex. You don't tell the printer to do so.

Comment: IF the printer "CanDuplex", you set its Duplex property to the value you want it to use. Horizontal for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this on this forum and others and not found an easy solution.  But one does exist.

What I ended up doing is creating a DUPLICATE printer entry where I set it up to do duplexing:

[Screen capture of printer properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCo5x.png)

and my vb.net code is as follows:

```
Dim wordApp As New Application
Dim wordDoc As New Document

wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(dirDocuments & "your filename goes here.docx")
wordApp.Visible = False

wordApp.ActivePrinter = "HP CL6015 for Catalogs"
wordDoc.PrintOut()

wordApp.Quit()
```

Just remember you need to install Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and I include the following import for my form class:

```
Imports Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
```

That's all that is needed.

As for background on this project, I have a lot of catalogs that can be mail ordered and I print on demand (hence the HP 6015 printer) and to speed things up, in the database I put the catalog filename and then when needed, just print it out from the vb.net application.

*** This code is written with VS 2022 v. 17.7.5 (64-bit); .NET Framework v. 4.8.09032